# Send an array of data to MQTT broker

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

I have an array of data like this:

```
plist = [
        ["name1", "address1"],
        ["name2", ["address2"],
        ["name3", "address3"]
        ....
        ]
```

and I need to send it to an MQTT broker. AFAIK, MQTT only supports Buffer or String. How can I convert my array into an MQTT-compatible type, keeping the structure intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a none language specific encoding, e.g. JSON or ProtoBuf